# 94 characters one line task, circle-intersection

Tags: javascript, geometry, intersection

I found a challenge here:

https://www.codewars.com/kata/one-line-task-circle-intersection/train/javascript

Write a function that that takes two points and the radius of the two same size circles and return the area of the intersection of two circles.

`with(Math)circleIntersection=([a,b],[c,d],r)=>(l=hypot(a-c,b-d)/2/r)>1?0:2*r*r*(acos(l)-l*sqrt(1-l*l))|0`

It said that the function should have no more than 94 characters. I have done my best to shorten the function, still got 104 characters( function name can't been changed).
Any idea to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

I really think that my answer is the best :-)

```js
with(Math)circleIntersection=([a,b],[c,d],r)=>(-sin(x=2*acos(hypot(a-c,b-d)/2/r))+x)*r*r|0
```

Comment: I use the same idea. But with python, my code exceed code limit :(

Comment: at least choose me as correct asnswer or somthing :-)